# What should be my expectations for Haskell's "deriving"?

Tags: haskell, parametric-polymorphism

Apologies in advance for a beginner question, but I have struggled to find useful info on this. I was working through "Learn You Haskell for Great Good" and am trying to understand the deriving keyword, which seems like Java's implements but supposedly with cool automatic code generation because of the category theory stuff or something. I declare a data structure for 2-vectors like

```
data R2 = R2 {x :: Double, y :: Double} deriving (Show)
```

Then I can use it for things like

```
show (R2 1.0 2.0)
```

Now what I'd like to do is vector addition and scalar multiplication, like

```
(2.0 * (R2 1.0 2.0)) + (R2 3.0 4.0)
```

but when I try

```
Prelude> data R2 = R2 { x :: Double, y :: Double} deriving (Num,Show)
     <interactive>:3:52:
     Can't make a derived instance of `Num R2':
         `Num' is not a derivable class
     In the data declaration for `R2'
```

So the compiler figured out how to show the cartesian product of primitive types, but addition is too hard? Maybe Num isn't the right type class to derive? How often can one expect to derive a type class and get working code without additional work, like how I didn't have to write my own show function?

Thanks very much,

John

Comment: `Num` isn't the correct class for vectors, though. It declares the [`signum`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:signum) function, for example, and there is no standard definition of this function for vectors.

Answer (score 6):

> trying to understand the deriving keyword, which seems like Java's implements but supposedly with cool automatic code generation

`instance` is a bit more like `implements`, in that you state that a type is an instance of a type class and then write the implementations. `deriving` is all about the cool automatic generation of those implementations (though it does subsume `instance`).

> How often can one expect to derive a type class and get working code without additional work, like how I didn't have to write my own show function?

Alexey Romanov's answer covers for which classes `deriving` works. There is also another way to auto-generate instances: using *generics*. From a bird's eye view, it works like this: you describe what an instance should look like for a generic type and then, for any type you want to have an instance, derive `Generic` and add an empty (i.e. with no implementations, as they will be generated automatically) `instance` declaration. Some libraries like `aeson` and `binary` [offer generic instances ready to use](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17502603/2751851), and you can of course [roll your own](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17416575/2751851) for your classes.

Answer (score 5):

See https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.10.2/docs/html/users_guide/deriving.html:

> In Haskell 98, the only classes that may appear in the deriving clause are the standard classes Eq, Ord, Enum, Ix, Bounded, Read, and Show.

GHC also allows deriving `Generic`, `Functor`, `Data`, `Typeable`, `Foldable` and `Traversable` for `data` declarations, and any classes for `newtype` declarations (after enabling the relevant extensions, as listed in the linked page).

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Seems very odd that I could derive Ord, which is meaningless in R^2, but there is no way to define addition through polymorphism for a cartesian product of primitives, literally the simplest case I could imagine. I guess I'm missing the point of how this is better than dumb old subtype polymorphism.

Answer (score 5):

Here's one reason that you can't derive the Num class

```
data Vector = Vector Int Int

instance Num Vector where
    Vector a b + Vector c d = Vector (a + c) (b + d)
    Vector a b * Vector c d = Vector (a * c) (b * d)

data Complex = Complex Int Int

instance Num Complex where
    Complex a b + Complex c d = Complex (a + c) (b + d)
    Complex a b * Complex c d = Complex (a * c - b * d) (a * d + b * c)
```

Both are sensible instances that a real programmer might want to define. For a given data definition with two `Int` fields, which instance should the `deriving` clause pick?

Comment: I've never seen anyone multiply vectors like that...? By your argument, I might like to show the R2 vectors in the struct I wrote differently than the default, but the compiler did something sensible I assume could be overridden.

Comment: @flagrant2 It's the [Hadamard product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)).

Comment: @flagrant2 How would you define the `signum` method of the `Num` class, e.g. what is the sign of the vector (1, -1)? There are so many arbitrary choices to make in implementing a derived `Num` instance that it would cause more trouble than it is worth. I think the extra 5-6 lines required to write your own `Num` instance isn't too much to ask.

It's acknowledged that the `Num` type class is a bit of a wart in Haskell, and I believe that there are some efforts to reform it, but they will be slow going, since people will already have written code that depends on the current implementation.

Answer (score 4):

The [Haskell Report 2010](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch11.html#x18-18200011) (the document that describes the Haskell language and which all implementions should follow) defines the conditions for deriving a class `C` as follows:

> 1. C is one of `Eq`, `Ord`, `Enum`, `Bounded`, `Show`, or `Read`.
> 2. There is a context `cx′` such that `cx′ ⇒ C tij` holds for each of the constituent types `tij`.
> 3. If `C` is `Bounded`, the type must be either an enumeration (all constructors must be nullary) or have only one constructor.
> 4. If `C` is `Enum`, the type must be an enumeration.
> 5. There must be no explicit instance declaration elsewhere in the program that makes `T u1 … uk` an instance of `C`.
> 6. If the data declaration has no constructors (i.e. when n = 0), then no classes are derivable.

Also, later in the report, it is said that it's also possible to [derive `Data.Ix` instances](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch19.html#x27-22700019.2).

To find out how a particular instance is derived exactly (for example, what does the derived `Show` instance output?), read the [section about it](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch11.html#x18-18200011) in the report. That section only gives implementations for the cases where the above conditions are met. That's why it's impossible to derive `Num` instances: it's not specified what that instance should do!

---

GHC also provides a few extensions that make allow for deriving more classes.
Those extensions are not part of standard Haskell, so they have to enabled explicitly. For example, if `GenericNewtypeDeriving` is enabled, you can write the following:

```
newtype MyInt = MyInt Int deriving (Num)
-- By GenericNewtypeDeriving, GHC will just "copy" the instance 
-- for the base type of the newtype, in this case, it'll use the `Num Int` instance.
```

You can read about these extensions in the [GHC user guide](http://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/deriving.html#deriving-extra)

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, deriving only works for a small handful of classes, where the necessary code is hard-wired into the compiler. You can write instances yourself for *any* class, but only this small handful can be derived *automatically*.